# Automatically generate required Plotly data structure

Tags: python-3.x, plotly

I wanted to generate an interactive scatter plot in Python3 using Plotly. Plotly requires the input for the data to be in a specific format. I would like to be able to generate the format automatically because I have a lot of data.

Plotly requires data for the scatter plot in the following format

```
fig = {
    'data': [
  {
        'x': sim_corr.AAK1, 
        'y': sim_pas.AAK1, 
        'text': sim_corr.index, 
        'mode': 'markers', 
        'name': 'AAK1'},
        {
        'x': sim_corr.ABL1, 
        'y': sim_pas.ABL1, 
        'text': sim_corr.index, 
        'mode': 'markers', 
        'name': 'ABL1'},
            {
        'x': sim_corr.ABL2, 
        'y': sim_pas.ABL2, 
        'text': sim_corr.index, 
        'mode': 'markers', 
        'name': 'ABL2'}
],
    'layout': {
        'title':'Correlation VS PAS',
        'hovermode':'closest',
        'xaxis': {'title': 'Correlations'},
        'yaxis': {'title': "PAS"}
    }
}
```

where sim_corr and sim_pas are two pandas data frames and AAK1 is a column name found in both data frames. Above is only 3 columns out of 207. I have generated the plot by manually inputting each column, but I am sure there is a more efficient way. I really do not have a clue to how this will be done.

Here is code to produce similar data frames on a smaller scale,

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[1,2,3,4], [4,5,6,7], [7,8,9,10], [10,11,12,13]], index = ["a", 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = [[4,2,5,4], [1,5,3,7], [2,8,5,10], [3,11,7,13]], index = ["a", 'b', 'c', 'd'], columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4'])
```

The expected results would be to automatically generate the data input in the required structure for all the columns in two data frames that share the exact same column names.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I found a way to creating this plot much faster than manually entering the data. First create a list of the column names in your first dataframe. using the example code provided above:

```
g = []
for i in range(0,len(df1.columns)):
    x = str("df1." + df1.columns[i])
    g.append(x)
```

second create a list of the column names in your second data frame.

```
h = []
for i in range(0,len(df2.columns)):
    x = str("df2." + df2.columns[i])
    h.append(x)
```

finally create a list of dictionaries while iterating over the column names in the two lists created in steps 1 and 2:

```
dics = []
for i in range(0,len(df1.columns)):
    d = {'x': g[i],
         'y': h[i],
         'text':df1.index,
         'mode':'markers',
         'name':str(df1.columns[i])}
    dics.append(d)
```

Now dics contains the data input in the format required. If anyone knows of an even more efficient way please add it below.

Comment: This the way to go for the moment. I'm doing this for every bigger project I'm building. :) Stil very inefficient for big data sets.